# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ta'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror, rsi, pandas-ta

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta

macd = data['CLOSE'].ta.macd(fast=12, slow=26, signal=9)
data = pd.concat([data, macd], axis=1)

data['RSI14'] = data['CLOSE'].ta.rsi(length=14)

data['EMA10'] = data['CLOSE'].ta.ema(length=10)
```

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ta'
```

And I did `!pip install pandas_ta` already.

So can't get what's wrong with `ta`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but it'd probably help to post the [full error message with traceback](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_24564\2584789719.py in ?()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import pandas_ta as ta
      3 
      4 
----> 5 macd = data['CLOSE'].ta.macd(fast=12, slow=26, signal=9)
      6 data = pd.concat([data, macd], axis=1)
      7 
      8 

~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ?(self, name)
   5985             and name not in self._accessors
   5986             and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5987         ):

Comment: 5988             return self[name]
-> 5989         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ta'

Comment: [Edit] the question. Comments don't support block formatting. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips.

Comment: Your code refers to a variable called `data` without showing how that variable was created.  It's hard for us to help if you do not share the full code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! Solved! :-)

Comment: If you're not going to share **how** you solved it, then it's best to just delete the question.

Comment: New here so didn't figure everything out yet but im in process.

Comment: Did it this way:
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta

data['EMA'] = data['CLOSE'].ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()

data['RSI14'] =ta.rsi(data['CLOSE'], length=14)

macd=ta.macd(data['CLOSE'])

and it worked with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

As said by the OP in comments, this is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
data['EMA'] = data['CLOSE'].ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()
data['RSI14'] = ta.rsi(data['CLOSE'], length=14)
macd = ta.macd(data['CLOSE'])
```